# Every point in set has a closed neighbourhood in set

Tags: general-topology

I'm looking for common properties of an open and not closed set A that would imply that every point $x$ in said set $A$ has a closed neighbourhood that is fully contained in $A$.

This holds trivially for open sets in Euclidean spaces, and for $T2\frac{1}{2}$ spaces; hoping for something more general than the former and simpler than the latter.

Comment: Typically a neighborhood of a point $x$ in a topological space is a set $A$ with non empty interior $A^o$ and such that $x\in A^o$. More often than not, people consider only neighborhoods that are already open.

Comment: Yes, hence the question!

Comment: In general a *pink* neighborhood of a point $x$ is a *pink* set whose interior contains $x$. (pink could be compact, closed, convex (in the case of topological linear space), etc.) There are axiomatic constructions of topologies in terms of neighborhoods (of whatever color). Old text books on point-set topology (1950's-60's) cover such constructions.

Comment: True, edited to exclude closed sets. Thanks.

Comment: @OliverDíaz What changes with the new ones?

Comment: @FShrike: The space should be $T_{2\tfrac12}$ then (by definition)